# D3 ColorBrewer Coloring on Dynamic Scales

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, colorbrewer

I'm using [dc.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js) which sits on top of D3.  Problem is all my charts have the same color bars like:

[image]

Its not easy to set the domain for different colors because none of my charts are static and the values on x/y axis could always be different.  How could I just tell the chart to dynamically change the colors for each group?  The example above code looks like:

```
 var chart = dc.barChart(elm);
 chart.barPadding(0.1)
 chart.outerPadding(0.05)
 chart.brushOn(false)
 chart.x(d3.scale.ordinal());
 chart.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal);
 chart.elasticY(true);
 chart.width(250).height(250)
 chart.render();
```

I've tried adding something like:

```
 chart.range(colorbrewer.RdBu[9]);
```

but then all the charts turn the same color too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want something like:

```
chart.colors(d3.scale.category20b());
```

to assign a color to each bar. If you want the color that's selected to be based of the value of the bar's data:

```
chart.colorAccessor(function(d, i){return i;})
```

These methods and more are documented here: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#color-mixin

Comment: Wow, too easy.  I dont know how i overlooked that.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: FWIW something I've found very helpful is the [annotated source](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html) for the DC [demo page](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/).

Comment: One other question on DC, why does the row chart animate nicely but the bar chart just appears?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'd try adding a transition in a renderlet: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#renderletrenderletfunction

Comment: Note: if using colorbrew you need to do something like: `chart.ordinalColors(colorbrewer["GrBlu"][size])` instead of just colors